# prototype get variable in evaluated ajax request

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, eval

Hi is there a way with prototype to get the value of a variable defined in a script evaluated in an ajax call? As far as I can see ajax requests are made inside a setTimeout closure so the scope of the variable is limited inside there..but maybe I'm missing something!

**For example:**

*External script:*

```
<script>
  var foo = "bar";
</script>
```

*Ajax call:*

```
new Ajax.Request(external_script, {
  evalScripts: true,
  onComplete: function () {
    //some magic
    console.log(foo);
  }
});
```

Comment: An external script shouldn't have `<script>` tags. It just contains the Javascript.

Comment: I don't see the `evalScripts` option at http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/. Should that be `evalJS`?

Comment: The external script is in the html response of the ajax call, sorry I didn't explained it well.

Comment: It doesn't look like Prototype will execute those scripts. In jQuery they'll only be executed if you insert the HTML response into the DOM using `.html()` or `.load()`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<script>` tag from the external JS file. An external JS file should just contain Javascript code.  `<script>` is only used for embedding Javascript in HTML files.

And according to the Prototype.js [Ajax](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/) documentation, the option to enable execution of scripts is `evalJS`, not `evalScripts`.